# Cannot run script 'npm run dev' in sveltekit project using vite config

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I'm a beginner who would start learning Svelte using SvelteKit, once I already installed the required quick start to run the project, I'm facing this kind of stuff when trying to run `npm run dev` script.

```
failed to load config from C:\Users\John Doe\Desktop\svelte\svelteKit\my-app\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:149:18)
```

What could have caused this and what should I do?

Many articles said it could be caused by the npm/node version being outdated, my npm version is 9.5.1 and node version is 18.16.0.

Answer (score 1):

Node 18+ should be able to handle `??=`, do you maybe have a different version than the primary installed one?

Either way, you should be able to work around this by replacing the offending statements with older syntax:

```js
variable = variable ?? fallback;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try updating your npm with `npm install -g npm@latest`
2. Clear your npm cache with `npm cache clean --force`
3. Delete the node modules folder in your project directory (`node_modules`) and try reinstalling them with `npm i`. Then try `npm run dev` again. It should work.
   The error might be a config issue since you stated that you're using Node 18.16.0, which should work.
   The first step should fix the problem. But if all these steps don't work, reinstall node and npm.
   Good luck.